# Make Guzzle trust self-signed certificate?

Tags: php, certificate, guzzle, self-signed, self-signed-certificate

With [Guzzle HTTP client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) I know you can set `new GuzzleClient(['verify' => false])` to have it not check the certificate, eg. when you are using a self-signed certificate. But how can I make it accept and trust a *specific* self-signed certificate, so that you don't just open up for ANY certificate but only one specific one - is that possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at the other options for `verify`, like documented at https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/request-options.html#verify?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A self-signed certificate is its own authority, so simply set the verify option to the filename of the certificate:

```
// Use a custom SSL certificate on disk.
new GuzzleClient(['verify' => '/path/to/self-signed/cert.pem']);
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify-option